# jquery datepicker doesn't activate if focus moves to it by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/scripts/demo/jquery-datepicker.html

If you click outside of the textarea and reclick inside of it a calendar will appear. How can I make it appear when the page is first loaded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('show');
});
```

This should give you the date picker without setting the focus.

Answer (score 2):

This should work,

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').focus();
});
```

but the whole Jquery lib is not corectly included.

Try grabing jquery with :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display it on DOM Ready:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker('show');
});
```

Also on the demo link you posted you are loading the jQuery js/css files from `jqueryui.com` domain and you get a 403 Forbidden HTTP error, so jQuery is not loaded.

If you want to use a CDN you should use http://code.jquery.com/. You will find both JS and CSS URLs there for jQuery and jQuery UI themes.